# What are the advantages of a condenser mic for recording vocals?

Tags: microphone, recording, home-studio, vocals, purchase-advice

Or it's better to buy a dynamic microphone?

I heard that condenser mics is too sensitive and there will be a lot of noises on the record.

Is that statement true?

Comment: What do you want to record? They both have pros and cons, it depends on your application.

Comment: @Simon, I want to record vocal

Comment: For those who downvoting, please let me know how can I improve my question and make it more valuable for community.

Comment: I recommend changing your question title to "What are the advantages of a condenser mic for recording vocals?".

Answer (score 2):

"...is that statement true?"

No, that statement is wrong. Whilst they are more sensitive they're are still directional and will reject sound from the sides. Most home studio owners own a condenser.

Answer (score 1):

I own the sontronics stc 3x and use it at home all the time it has a unidirectional polar pattern which helps to reject some of the background noise , and quality turns out to be decent.

Answer (score 1):

While condensers are the de-facto standard for vocal recording, they are not strictly required. Many recordings do fine with dynamic mcs and maybe even better depending on the style of music (screaming vocals for one example).

As Hi-Tech USA mentioned in their answer, you will need to be careful about using pre-amp gain with condensers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are recording vocals, then Yes you need a Condenser Microphone.

> "I heard that condenser mics is too sensitive and there will be a lot
>   of noises on the record."

Condenser microphones do pick up more noise but that is also why they are usually used to record vocals. They pick up much more detail. You will need a 48v Phantom power source from a mixer or a recording interface. My Presonus Firepod has phantom power built in with on -off button.

Look at a Rode NT2 for a god low price high quality mic. AKG makes a few decent ones for very little money.

Be sure to read up on levels when recording through Condenser mics. If you get the mic pre to hot, you'll catch to much air and noise but if it's not hot enough, you won't have the rich sound you want.
Read and practice, practice, then read some more!